# Ion Nav Bar place over the Barcode Scanner

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue with Ionic. I have the Barcode Scanner  from Phonegap Bar implemented and it works fine. My problem is that i want the Navbar showing while having the Barcode Scanner activated/open, but the barcode scanner is always in full screen and ignores the navbar.

How can i do that?

My tab-scanner.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Scanner">
  <ion-content>
    <center>
      <!-- Beim Klick des Buttons wird die Methode Scan() ausgeführt -->
      <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="scan()">
        Scan
      </button>
      <!-- Methode Fetch wird mit dem Parameter blabla ausgeführt -->
      <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="fetch(4001513007704)">
        Ean
      </button>
    </center>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

My Scanner-Controller:
.controller('ScannerCtrl', function($scope, dataService, dataFactory) {
  $scope.scan = function() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
      $scope.fetch(result.text); 
    }, function(error) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  };

  $scope.fetch = function(ean) {
    dataService.eanData(ean).then(function(dataResponse) {
      dataFactory.setData(dataResponse.data);
    });
  };
})
```

Images from the app:
[If you click on the scan button the scanner is opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Stgtv.png)

[The scanner is here in fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBNd.jpg)

Comment: had you tried positioning for navbar and barcode scanner  ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: have you tried positioning on Navigation bar  and barcode scanner .

Comment: I didn't know how to do it so I'm pretty sure that i didn't try that. Can you give me some example code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the plugin's code. In PhoneGap plugin directory (in your ionic project) extract .aar file with WinRAR, 7Zip, etc...

[image]

Then look in `res/layout` [image]

capture.xml is the file you need to rewrite, use Android Studio to design your view activity like that:
Here you can redesign the view, adding new buttons, and other things [image]